# Emacs hangs on org-babel-execute-src-block for Haskell blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, doom, haskell-mode

I have a minimal org file with a Haskell code block:

```
#+begin_src haskell
putStrLn "Hello World"
#+end_src
```

When I do `M-x org-babel-execute-src-block`, Emacs hangs with minibuffer saying: `executing Haskell code block`. If I `toggle-debug-on-quit` in advance and `C-g` during the hang, I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  accept-process-output(#<process haskell>)
  org-babel-interpret-haskell("putStrLn \"Hello World!\"" ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:session . "none") (:cache . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:tangle . "no") (:padlines . "no")))
  org-babel-execute:haskell("putStrLn \"Hello World!\"" ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:session . "none") (:cache . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:tangle . "no") (:padlines . "no")))
  org-babel-execute-src-block()
  funcall-interactively(org-babel-execute-src-block)
  command-execute(org-babel-execute-src-block record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-babel-execute-src-block" nil)
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-babel-execute-src-block" nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Not sure how to debug it further.

Environment. emacs-pgtkgcc (nominally 29.0.50). I use Doom Emacs and [my configuration is here](https://github.com/ulysses4ever/dotfiles/tree/main/doom.d). My Haskell environment should be fine (e.g. I can call GHCi in the terminal).

**UPD** Here's what I see in the `*haskell*` (Inf-Haskell) buffer:

```
GHCi, version 8.10.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /nix/store/rbdsn8kzkagrb604mhjbcizb5z44cq18-hm_.ghci
λ> λ> putStrLn "Hello World!"
"org-babel-haskell-eoe"
Hello World!
λ> "org-babel-haskell-eoe"
λ>
```

Comment: It sounds as if there is no inferior haskell process to communicate with. You can check with `M-x list-processes`. Check whether you have `inf-haskell` installed. Also make sure to read the `Commentary` section of the `ob-haskell.el` [file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ob-haskell.el). [This page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Emacs/Inferior_Haskell_processes) might also be useful.

Comment: This (old) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081379/how-to-set-up-org-babel-for-haskell-with-stack) might also be somewhat helpful (but keep in mind that it is old and possibly outdated - and I know no more Haskell now than I knew back then :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Nothing caught my eye in the docs or prior art (i.e. your old answer). Inferior process does appear to start: when I open a fresh Emacs instance, it has two processes listed: emacs server and ispell; then, when I do `org-babel-execute-src-block` and `C-g` after it hangs, I see a new process in the list: `haskell 110816 run *haskell* /dev/pts/3 Main ghci -ferror-spans`.

Comment: OK - it would have been easier if the lack of communication was from a missing process :-) You might want to visit the `*haskell*` buffer and see what's going on there: that might provide a clue. The Org babel code pays attention to the *prompt* that's output in that buffer when one sends commands to it, so you might want to add that to your question.

Comment: @NickD you nailed it. I looked into the buffer and noticed 2 lambda chars (added to my post here). One lambda comes from my `.ghci` file — that's how I like my prompt in regular GHCi sessions. Removing the file fixed org-babel execution. A cleaner solution is to customize `haskell-process-args-ghci` to add `"-ignore-dot-ghci"` to it. Do you want to turn it into an answer, so that I can accept it and bump your karma? Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: Sure - I'll do that at some point. It's actually a more general point about org-babel sessions, so I might try to do a bit of research and write a comprehensive answer. Glad you got your problem resolved!